# How to build gcc 4.7.2 on CentOS 6 x64

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos, centos6

I am trying to build latest (at the moment of writing this) GCC version on CentOS.
I downloaded & built GMP, MPFR and MPC. These libraries are located under /usr/local (i. e. usr/local/lib for libraries and /usr/local/include for includes). Now I am trying to configure GCC to build with following command:

```
./configure --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-mpfr=/usr/local --with-mpc=/usr/local
```

And I get following error message:

```
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpfr.h... yes
checking for the correct version of mpc.h... yes
checking for the correct version of the gmp/mpfr/mpc libraries... no
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.3.1+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify their locations.
```

What may be the reason? Libraries are build, location is correct, header files are recognized, but libraries themselves are not. I also tried this:

```
./configure --with-gmp-lib=/usr/local/lib \
--with-mpfr-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-mpc-lib=/usr/local/lib
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks, I investigated myself; the problem is that in CentOS 6 there are pre-installed old versions of GMP/MPFR/MPC, and they conflicted with my new built libraries.

Comment: I hope you are enabling plugins at configure time. Then you might be interested by http://gcc-melt.org/

Answer (score 5):

Highly recommend using GCC SRC (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/)

You need to have Python and bzr installed first.

Then after configuration (steps in gsrc webpage), simply do these in the gsrc directory

make -C gnu/gcc
make -C gnu/gcc install

Answer (score 0):

Someone's made a script to do that. It addresses the issue of library dependencies on these libraries and dependencies among themselves.
http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=811

It worked for me with some minor modification, but the resulting gcc has whacky link path (it generates binaries that still look for libstdc++.so in the regular system paths which contain old libraries. I have a question on this:

[How to build and install gcc with built-in rpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334300/)