# How to build and install gcc with built-in rpath?

Tags: gcc, build, centos, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build and install my own gcc 4.7.2 in /usr/local to use in place of the gcc 4.4.6 in /usr. (This is on CentOS 6.3.)

gcc makes executables and dynamic libraries that dynamically link to its own dynamic libraries, e.g. libstdc++.so. How do I build and install gcc so that the generated binaries automatically get a linker -rpath option (-rpath /usr/local/lib64) that causes dynamic libraries in /usr/local/lib64 to be linked instead of those in /usr/lib64 or /lib64?

If it works properly, after I build an executable with the gcc without specifying "-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64", when I ldd the executable, it should show /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 instead of /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6. Similarly for the libgcc_s.so.1.

I have tried different approaches, including specifying LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64,-rpath=/usr/local/lib on the 'configure' command-line, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to export paths there's an alternative solution:

with your toolchain in the `PATH`:

```
gcc -dumpspecs > specsfile
```

edit `specsfile` and in the section `link` add your `-rpath` example:

```
*link:
%{!static:--eh-frame-hdr} -m %(link_emulation) %{shared:-shared}   %{!shared:     %{!static:       %{rdynamic:-export-dynamic}       -dynamic-linker %(dynamic_linker)}       %{static:-static}} -rpath /usr/local/lib64
```

at this point you can test if it work with:

```
g++ -specs=specsfile test.cpp
readelf -d a.out |grep RPATH
```

if it work you can make it permanent (no need to pass `-specs` everytime)

```
strace -fF -o /tmp/g++.log g++ test.cpp
grep specs /tmp/g++.log
```

the grep should show the paths where `gcc` look for the default `specs` file.

The [specs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) files are flexible enough to allow conditional linking depending on variables, example:

```
{!static: %{mabi=n32:-rpath-link %R/lib32:%R/usr/lib32} %{mabi=64:-rpath-link %R/lib64:%R/usr/lib64} %{mabi=32:-rpath-link %R/lib:%R/usr/lib}}
```

should use different and multiple paths depending on mabi (untested, yet), `%R` should be the `sysroot` path, can be changed with needed full path.

There's also a `--with-specs=` option [gcc configure](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) eventually to be used at build time<s>, not clear to me yet how to use with the `link` section (working on it)</s>.

```
--with-specs="%{shared:-Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(DESTDIR)/lib}%{!shared:-Wl,-rpath -Wl,$(DESTDIR)/lib}"
```

It work, I used both `shared` and not `!shared` just for test, probably some smarter condition should be used, note that it isn't reported with `-dumpspecs`.

Reading through some thread of the gcc mailing list I had the impression `specs` aren't liked by everyone (but if I'm not wrong 4.9 add another option `--with-extra-specs`) instead preferred way to do such customizations appears to be `configure.host`, but I'm done and not looking into it, have fun! :-)

see also: [gcc faq rpath](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#rpath)

**update above**

I don't know if you can set a pre-defined `rpath`, probably if you can would be in the linker `ld` of `binutils` not in `gcc/g++`, but why would you do that?

Just export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime and `LD_RUN_PATH` at build time

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ldd a.out
```

`ldd` should show the paths you exported.

To quote a message given when a shared library is built with libtool:

> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR' flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable during execution
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable during linking
> - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
> - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
>
> See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
>   more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.

**for completeness**
the `Makefile` I used for testing the thing, all the configure options, environment variables (see boot ldflags) I tried didn't work, `--enable-rpath` included.

use with `mkdir ~/gcc` copy the `Makefile` below into `~/gcc` then `cd ~/gcc && make build-gcc`

**notice** the options used are only for this test case, don't use as reference.

```
FETCH = aria2c --file-allocation=none -c -d dl
NICE = nice -n 19
PARALLEL = -j4
DESTDIR = $(HOME)/gcc/install
SRCDIR = $(HOME)/gcc/src

all:

# if more downloads are added just remove {dl,src}/*-my-stamp not the .bak
# the .bak should avoid to rebuild targets because of timestamp
touch_stamp = if [ -f $@.bak ]; then \
        touch -r $@.bak $@; \
    else \
        touch $@ $@.bak; \
    fi

dl/dl-my-stamp:
    $(FETCH) https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
    $(FETCH) http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
    $(FETCH) ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz
    $(FETCH) https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
    $(FETCH) --check-certificate=false http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/binutils/snapshots/binutils-2.24.51.tar.bz2 \
        ftp://sourceware.org/pub/binutils/snapshots/binutils-2.24.51.tar.bz2
    $(touch_stamp)

untar_dep = src/untar-my-stamp
src/untar-my-stamp: dl/dl-my-stamp
    mkdir -p src
    tar -C src -xjf dl/gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2
    tar -C src -xjf dl/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
    tar -C src -xzf dl/mpc-0.8.1.tar.gz
    tar -C src -xjf dl/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
    tar -C src -xjf dl/binutils-2.24.51.tar.bz2
    $(touch_stamp)

define configure-rule
$(1)_install = $(DESTDIR)/$(1)-install-my-stamp
$(1)_builddir = $$($(1)_dir)/build
$(DESTDIR)/$(1)-install-my-stamp: $$($(1)_deps)
    mkdir -p $$($(1)_builddir)
    cd $$($(1)_builddir) && \
        $$($(1)_env) ../configure --cache-file=$(SRCDIR)/$(1)-config.cache \
            $$($(1)_configure)
    $(NICE) make -C $$($(1)_builddir) $$($(1)_make_target) $(PARALLEL)
ifneq ($$($(1)_post_make),)
    $$($(1)_post_make)
endif
    touch $$@
.PHONY: build-$(1) clean-$(1)
build-$(1): $$($(1)_install)
clean-$(1):
    -rm -fr $$($(1)_builddir)
endef

gmp_dir = src/gmp-4.3.2
gmp_env =   CONFIG_SITE=$(SRCDIR)/config.site
gmp_configure = --prefix=$(DESTDIR) \
                --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-cxx
gmp_deps = $(untar_dep)
gmp_make_target = install
$(eval $(call configure-rule,gmp))

mpfr_dir = src/mpfr-2.4.2
mpfr_env =  CONFIG_SITE=$(SRCDIR)/config.site
mpfr_configure = --prefix=$(DESTDIR) \
                --disable-shared --enable-static \
                --with-gmp=$(DESTDIR)
mpfr_deps = $(untar_dep) $(gmp_install)
mpfr_make_target = install
$(eval $(call configure-rule,mpfr))

mpc_dir = src/mpc-0.8.1
mpc_env =   CONFIG_SITE=$(SRCDIR)/config.site
mpc_configure = --prefix=$(DESTDIR) \
                --disable-shared --enable-static \
                --with-gmp=$(DESTDIR) --with-mpfr=$(DESTDIR)
mpc_deps = $(untar_dep) $(gmp_install) $(mpfr_install)
mpc_make_target = install
$(eval $(call configure-rule,mpc))

gcc_dir = src/gcc-4.7.2
gcc_env =   CONFIG_SITE=$(SRCDIR)/config.site \
    CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu" \
    CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu"
gcc_configure = --prefix=$(DESTDIR) \
                --libdir=$(DESTDIR)/lib \
                --with-local-prefix=$(DESTDIR) \
                --with-gmp=$(DESTDIR) --with-mpfr=$(DESTDIR) \
                --with-mpc=$(DESTDIR) \
                --disable-bootstrap \
                --enable-languages=c,c++ \
                --disable-libgomp --disable-multilib \
                --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp \
                --disable-libquadmath \
                --enable-rpath \
                MAKEINFO=missing
gcc_deps = $(untar_dep) $(gmp_install) $(mpfr_install) $(mpc_install)
gcc_make_target = 
gcc_post_make = make -C $(gcc_builddir) install
$(eval $(call configure-rule,gcc))

binutils_dir = src/binutils-2.24.51
#binutils_env = LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath\ $(DESTDIR)/lib
binutils_env = CONFIG_SITE=$(SRCDIR)/config.site \
    CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu" \
    BOOT_LDFLAGS="-rpath-link=$(DESTDIR)/lib -rpath=$(DESTDIR)/lib"
binutils_configure = --prefix=$(DESTDIR) \
                --libdir=$(DESTDIR)/lib \
                --with-gmp=$(DESTDIR) \
                --enable-rpath
binutils_deps = $(untar_dep) $(gmp_install)
#binutils_make_target = install
binutils_post_make = make -C $(binutils_builddir) install
$(eval $(call configure-rule,binutils))


.PHONY: env
env:
    @echo export PATH=$(DESTDIR)/bin:\$$PATH
    @echo export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I don’t know if this didn’t exist yet in 2014, but for now it’s probably a better idea to use `*link: + -rpath=/usr/local/lib64` than to actually modify the primary `*link` spec string line.

Comment: To use the right path for `-m32` as well as `-m64` you can use `--with-specs='%{!static:%{!m32:-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64}%{m32:-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib}}'`

Answer (score 0):

I was installing httpd-2.4.51 and needed to specify -rpath to compile the program. I use the linker flag `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR`.

Use commands:

```
sudo mv httpd.c /usr/lib #create a .c file and move it to the default directory for the library file
sudo gcc -o httpd httpd.c -L$--prefix=/usr/lib -lhttpd -Wl,-rpath=$--prefix=/usr/lib
```

Your can check where you have gcc installed:

```
whereis gcc
```

`gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz`