# Is it possible to change glibc's default rpath?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, glibc, toolchain

I have an embedded platform that I need to compile a newer version of gcc for (from 4.5.3 to 4.9).  Because of ABI changes (as far as I could tell it changed significantly between those versions) I need to recompile the entire toolchain (binutils, gcc, glibc).  After a overcoming a couple of problems here and there I have the new toolchain working, but there's just one thing that's quite annoying and I'm not sure how to change, and that's the default settings for the loader.

The embedded platform will contain two versions of gcc (both the old and new one) so I'm keeping them and their libraries in different directories.  The new one is installed in `/usr/local/gcc-4.9` and whenever I compile a new binary I need to add the following options `-Wl,--
rpath=/usr/local/gcc-4.9/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/gcc-4.9/lib/ld-linux.so.3` for it to find the correct libraries.

Is it possible to compile glibc with this new configuration built into it so that I don't have to add those options every time I compile a binary?

Comment: Don't think glibc has anything to do with rpath. It's just a DT_RPATH   entry in an ELF file, created by the linker. You may want to modify the linker, or perhaps the gcc specs fille, but not glibc.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334300/how-to-build-and-install-gcc-with-built-in-rpath.

Comment: @ks1322 You're right, that question is pretty much what I need.  I guess the problem was that I really didn't know _how_ to search for it.  Thank you very much.  Should I close this question?